# Событийно-ориентированное программирование

Tags: node.js, события, javascript, сокет

Пробую для своего проекта перенести серверную часть на использование node.js. Возникла задача, которую я не могу решить - не понимаю логику конструкции, которую нужно построить. Подробности в коде:

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
var parseUrl=url.parse(request.url,true),
    pathname = parseUrl.pathname,
    obj=parseUrl.query;
//console.log(parseUrl.query);
var answer="ERROR";
if(pathname=="/getdata") {
    if(obj.name != undefined && obj.pwd != undefined && obj.com != undefined) {
        answer=makeRequest(obj.name,obj.pwd,obj.com);
    } else {
        answer="error in data";
    }
} else {

}
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html", 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
response.write(answer);
response.end();
});
```

здесь, сервер обрабатывает клиентский запрос, но для ответа на него серверу нужно переслать данные на сокет другого сервера, получить данные и вернуть их назад, чтобы вернуть клиенту. от makeRequest(...) я хочу получить ответ от сокета, общение с которым покамест реализовано так:

```
function makeRequest(name,pwd,com) {

var client = new net.Socket(),answer=[],flag=0;
client.connect(3201, "127.0.0.1", function() {
    client.write('auth "'+name+'" "'+pwd+'"\n');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
     answer.push(data);
         if(data=='_bye') client.destroy();  
});

client.write(com+'\n');

client.on('close', function() {
    return answer; // вот это работать не будет. а мне нужно при закрытии сокетного
                   // соединения вернуть последний ответ в функцию, которая вызвала
                   // этот makeRequest(), т.е. как-то обернуть или замкнуть...
});

}
```

помогите пожалуйста грамотно составить такую конструкцию -- возврат данных из сокета, которые в свою очередь должен вернуть ответ на запрос серверу node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передайте в `makeRequest` callback, который будет вызван при закрытии соединения

```
// ...
makeRequest(obj.name, obj.pwd, obj.com, function(answer) {
    response.write(answer);
})
// ...
// ...
function makeRequest(name, pwd, com, onClose) {
    // ...
    client.on('close', function() {
        onClose(answer)
    });   
}
```

Ну, и остальной код надо будет поправить немного.

Comment: console.log('1');
    if(pathname=="/getdata") {
  if(obj.name != undefined && obj.pwd != undefined && obj.com != undefined) {
   makeRequest(obj.name,obj.pwd,obj.com, function(ans) {
    answer=ans.toString('utf-8',0,ans.length);
    console.log("makerequest answer: "+answer);
   });
  } else {
   answer="error in data";
  }
 } else {

 }
 console.log('2');  

выдает в консоль 1,2, "makerequest answer:", а мне нужно 1, "makerequest answer:", 2 - т.е. дождаться ответа из сокета и только потом вернуть его клиенту.

Comment: а вот если добавить в вызов makeRequest() вот это:  
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html", 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
    response.write("<pre>"+answer+"</pre>");
    response.end();  
то моя задача замечательно решается!!!.. 
спасибо за правильное целеуказание!

Answer (score 2):

`answer` должен обрабатывать `callback`, который `makeRequest` должна принимать в параметрах, т.е. что-то типа:

```
function makeRequest( bla, bla, bla, callback ) {
  // .....
  client.on('close', function(){ callback( answer ) })
}
if( obj.name && obj.pwd && obj.com ) {
  makeRequest( bla, bla, bla, handleAnswer)
}
else {
  handleAnswer( 'error in data' );
}

function handlerAnswer( answer ) {
  // check answer here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это у вас ничего не `EventDriven` подход. Это обычный процедурный подход, в рамках которого вы пишете какие-то костыли.

Классический `Event Driven` подход обычно строится вокруг цикла обработки событий и обмена сообщениями/событиями между процедурами и/или объектами.

У вас нет цикла обработки или диспетчера и есть нечто похожее на сообщения. Переработайте код в направлении появления цикла обработки - тогда все станет проще и яснее.

Comment: Сам цикл же скрыт под капотом node.js. Разве нет?

Comment: Бармалей, сможете привести пример относительно моей задачи?..